# Apache nifi doesn't start

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I've tried several times to run an Apache Nifi server, but it won't work. I'm using windows 8 and installed java version 8.

I get this error message:

> 'nifi-env.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.
> Instead the PATH will be used to find the java executable.

Error Screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp2fi.png]

I've tried the solution to the following similar problem, but this did not help:

[Nifi commands on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38822146/nifi-commands-on-windows)

I've also tried what is explained in this video, but this did not work either:
[How to Install Apache NiFi and run Simple Process](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKX6lMVmCWM)

What should I do in order to run the nifi?

Comment: What command did you run and from what directory location did you run it?

Comment: i just run, the file called run-nifi.bat and i put apache nifi in directory which not content white spaces

Comment: i put my apache nifi file, the folder which not contain white spaces.

Comment: Do you see `nifi-env.bat` under `/bin` in your NiFi directory?

Comment: @SahaniRajapakshe You seem to be new to stack overflow. You are most welcome to this community. If the answers published below solved your problem, click on the tick but if it didn't help u even after trying it out. Drop down a comment on the answer so that we can get back to trying to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be a Java installation error, which is affecting the `nifi-env.bat` file. Problem will be solved if you create a virtual environment with java. The following link explains how to [create a Java Virtual environment](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiu8cWZ6b7lAhWEf30KHVNnAdIQFjACegQIDRAG&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.geeksforgeeks.org%2Fsetting-environment-java%2F&usg=AOvVaw2YLaiWQI2Pvi2kXA2lXBaN). This will also solve the problem with `'nifi-env.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command` as in that case nifi would only be able to be run within the virtual environment.

Try to troubleshoot the problem by reinstalling java, if the above doesn't work out.

Answer (score 2):

I have pulling my hair off for this, but I discovered the directory which holds nifi, must have not spaces.

My folder's name was "apache nifi" and there I unzipped the download from apache nifi's website, but after one hour I realized the name *could be* the problem, and actually it was. I just changed folder's name from "apache nifi" to just "nifi" and voilá, it just runs.

Answer (score 0):

Check if JAVA_HOME path is set properly.

Comment: i did it.but it won't work.and another point is my case is not a java path in error message 2 line and 3 line usually get those who not set JAVA_HOME.My problem is why **nifi-env.bat** is rquesting?